# How to replace a sequential number series in Word with another sequential number series using wildcards

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I have a document where every number in the sequence 264-543 needs to be replaced with the number 2-281. Help!

Comment: Is the series just text, or have you used SEQ fields?  If it's a field, you should just need to tell it to start at 2 at the first instance.  But if text, you could create a SEQ field, copy it (so it is in clipboard) then do a wildcard find to find <[0-9]{1,3} (which should find numbers with 1 to 3 digits but would include any over 543 as well) and replace with ^c (the clipboard, which contains your SEQ field).  I'd step through find and replace - not replace all.  Then CTRL a then F9 to update all the SEQ fields, then edit the field code of the first SEQ to start at 2 with \r 2.

Comment: It is just text. It's an index and the book has been split into two volumes.